# create_streaming_live_table in DLT creates a VIEW instead of a delta table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

I have the following piece of code and able to run as a DLT pipeline successfully

```
@dlt.table(
        name = source_table
    )
    def source_ds():
        return spark.table(f"{raw_db_name}.{source_table}")


    ### Create the target table definition
    dlt.create_streaming_live_table(name=target_table,
         comment= f"Clean, merged {target_table}",
         #partition_cols=["topic"],
         table_properties={
             "quality": "silver"
         }
     )
```

If I try to view the history using time travel, am getting the error:
For eg.,

```
describe history my_db.employee_trasaction
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: Cannot describe the history of a view.
```

I need to also create a sync process so as to have these ables in Unity Catalog and am referring to this document (https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/03/how-seamlessly-upgrade-your-hive-metastore-objects-unity-catalog-metastore-using).

When I checked table properties, the type is shown as VIEW?
[image]

How do I make these tables as DELTA so they are available for time travel, and for unity catalog

When I tried sync command for EXTERNAL TABLES or VIEWS, am getting errors as VIEWS not supported
Screen shot for a sync command VIEW table:
[image]

Screen shot for a sync command for EXTERNAL tables:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make these tables as DELTA so they are available for time travel, and for unity catalog

edit: **As of August 2023**, [publishing to Unity Catalog](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/unity-catalog.html#write-tables-to-unity-catalog-from-a-delta-live-tables-pipeline) is supported.

Let me answer the last part of your question about Unity Catalog (UC).

What I learnt just recently is that you can [Publish data from Delta Live Tables pipelines](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-publish.html) (using **Target schema** in **Destination** section of a DLT pipeline's setting), but not to Unity Catalog (!)

> You cannot publish tables to Unity Catalog. Delta Live Tables supports publishing tables only to the workspace-level Hive metastore.

[image: Target schema]

Answer (score 2):

When implementing SCD Type 1 or 2, Delta Live Tables writes additional data that allows it to guarantee that you get correct data. To hide that additional data, it creates a view on top of the actual Delta Lake table. So you need to perform time travel on the actual Delta table whose name/path you can find in the view definition.

Regarding UC support, Jacek is correct - it's not available now, but should be available in the few months (I think that [quarterly roadmap webinar](https://www.databricks.com/p/webinar/productroadmapwebinar) mentioned that). As of right now you can use the [SYNC](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-sync.html) SQL command if you want to expose DLT tables in some UC catalog.

Comment: Views are not supported yet for sync commands, I have added screen shot for your reference. thanks